# Find exact amount of chars with MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, sql-like

My teacher is pointing to oracle and debating that, but I have hopes of doing this with a pure injection in MySQL. I want to search the database in phpMyadmin and find exactly two K's. Is this possible?

The nearest thing I got is:

```
SELECT etunimi, sukunimi FROM nimet WHERE sukunimi LIKE '%k%k%n';
```

It is the last `%k%k%n` that needs to be solved. Can you help me prove my teacher wrong?

Comment: Are you saying you saying you want to find repeated characters? Downvoted because I don't think the question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL's `REGEXP` operator:

```
SELECT etunimi, sukunimi
  FROM nimet
 WHERE sukunimi REGEXP '^[^k]*k[^k]*k[^k]*n$'
```

I'm not sure what the n at the end is for, since you don't mention it in your question, but I left it, just in case.

Comment: The end stands for a char that the seach should include as the last char as an must be included in the search. Kinda stupid, it is a very simple database that we are using, but all class social sec urity numbers are included, so I can't post it. :(

Comment: the query in my first post gives more than or exatly two K's, I want to find 2 k's nothing less and nothing more, is it possible, the regex above didn't work.

Comment: The regex should return all strings with exactly two K's. Did it not do this? Can you provide an example of a string that has more or less than two K's but still matched the above regex? That might help me to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to find out strings with exactly 2 k's

```
SELECT etunimi, sukunimi FROM nimet WHERE LENGTH(sukunimi)-LENGTH(REPLACE(sukunimi, 'k', ''))=2;
```